# Why are all of my Marketing Cloud queries off by just a little?

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I have a handful of queries that work together. The first one pulls all sends that occurred during the last full month by querying the _Sent data view.

```
SELECT
s.SubscriberKey,
s.JobID,
s.EventDate,
j.EmailName,
j.SchedTime as "Job Scheduled Time",
x.Name as Market
from _Sent s
INNER JOIN(
  SELECT l.id,c.Name
  FROM
  ENT.Lead_Salesforce l
  INNER JOIN ENT.Campaign_Salesforce c
  ON l.Consumer_newsletter__c = c.id
) x
ON s.SubscriberKey = x.Id
INNER JOIN _Job j
ON j.JobID = s.JobID

where
DATEPART(m, s.EventDate) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))
AND DATEPART(yyyy, s.EventDate) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE()))
```

The next, grabs open, clicks and unsubscribes from each respective data view (_open, _click, _unsubscribe) and matches it to the JobID to build a new table.

```
SELECT
s.JobID,s2.Sent,s.EmailName,s.EventDate,
(SELECT distinct slog.Market FROM SendLog slog with (NOLOCK) WHERE slog.JobID = s.JobID) as Market,
(SELECT count(o.JobID) FROM _Open o WHERE o.JobID = s.JobID AND o.EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND o.EventDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) as TotalOpens,
(SELECT count(o.JobID) FROM _Open o WHERE o.JobID = s.JobID AND o.EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND o.EventDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0) AND o.IsUnique = 1) as UniqueOpens,
(SELECT count(c.JobID) FROM _Click c WHERE c.JobID = s.JobID AND c.EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND c.EventDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) as TotalClicks,
(SELECT count(c.JobID) FROM _Click c WHERE c.JobID = s.JobID AND c.EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND c.EventDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0) AND c.IsUnique = 1) as UniqueClicks,
(SELECT count(u.JobID) FROM _Unsubscribe u WHERE u.JobID = s.JobID AND u.EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0) AND u.EventDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) as Unsubscribes
FROM [01_Sent Data View] s with (NOLOCK)
JOIN (
    SELECT JobID,count(SubscriberKey) as Sent
    FROM [01_Sent Data View]
    WHERE EventDate >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE())-1,0)
    AND EventDate < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0) 
    GROUP BY JobID
    ) s2
ON s.JobID = s2.JobID
```

There are some final steps, but the are irrelevant.

The two queries above give me ALMOST correct data. Some are off by 1, some are off by 2 or 3 and some are off by around 10. On a send of 400,000 being off by 10 is not really a big deal, but it's bugging me. Is there something wrong with my query? Or should I just accept this and let it go?

FYI, the triggered sends are more off, but I know why that is so it's not really an issue here. I'm mainly asking about the manual sends.

Comment: Do you have any subscribers who share an email address, who might have been de-duped in the sending process?

Comment: I'm not sure, what would that cause?

Comment: Depending on whether or not you chose 'De-duplicate subscribers by email address' when doing the send, you  might have sent to 2 subscribers who had the same email address, resulting in their open only being returned once in your opens query, for example.

Comment: I've also seen tiny discrepancies and realised when comparing with the original data it was sent to that some were suppressed as they had unsubscribed. This can help explain small numbers.

Comment: hmmm maybe, so it sounds like I should just let this go?

Comment: Certainly in my cases, I've always been able to explain it away quite simply by checking for duplicate email addresses in subscribers and anyone suppressed from the send at subscriber level. Every time I've spent a couple hours checking, I've been satisfied that nothing is awry!

Comment: I honestly don't think they're dupes because we bring them in from salesforce which does a lot of de-duping. It shouldn't even allow a same email address to create a new lead...

Comment: For me seems like at the time the queries runs, the data state is different for each run. The use of NOLOCK, means the data will change meanwhile I'm running the query. And as You create your  01_Sent Data View , in a fraction of second the data can change on the system Data Views, what creates some shift.